# Date comparison format in stored procedure

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, stored-procedures, formatting

I have a sql server 2005 database and a stored procedure that accepts two dates and does some comparisons on the data @start_date_from and @start_date_to both of which are of type DATETIME.

We are using LINQ to call the stored procedures from our code and dragging the stored procedure onto the LINQ surface generates a method call which accepts nullable datetimes.

The problem that I am facing is that our dates from the user interface are entered as dd/MM/yyyy (we're in Australia) and parsed as a C# DateTime.

Once the call to the stored proc occurs it seems to convert it to an american style date. I'm looking for a way to prevent this, hopefully without having to change the datatype of the parameters in the proc.

I have tried using SET DATEFORMAT dmy in the proc but it seems to have no affect, I assume it must need a GO or something to take effect.

I was considering maybe trying some funky formatting/conversion/casting once inside the stored proc but that seemed like a last resort.

I guess also I could change the input parameters to varchars and put the date in an unambigious format.

Within the proc itself the dates are using with the BETWEEN keyword (if that makes any difference).

So what other options (or which of the ones I've outlined) should I go with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that user input are implicit converted to DateTime? I would say that you need to parse user input to a valid DateTime before calling the SP.

```
DateTime.Parse("11/12/1981", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

If the culture is different between users you may want to use the current thread's culture:

```
DateTime.Parse("11/12/1981", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture);
```